# How to delete a Notification by clicking on a notification action button?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

I'm currently working on an Android App, that receives Push-notifications. Now the notifications I display usually have an action button, that should perform an action like shown in the code snippet below:

```
public class PushReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements RequestCallbacks {

    private RequestHandler requestHandlerInstance;
    private SessionHandler sessionHandlerInstance;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
        requestHandlerInstance = RequestHandler.getInstance(context);
        sessionHandlerInstance = SessionHandler.getInstance(context);

        String id = intent.getStringExtra("error_id");
        requestHandlerInstance.startRequest(new RequestOperation(RequestOperation.Type.ERROR_TAKE_OVER, sessionHandlerInstance.getDeviceHash(), id), this);
    }

    #these are callbacks that will be executed 
    #when starRequest() returns a response

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(JSONObject json, String parsingKey) {
        #request was successful
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(VolleyError error, String parsingKey) {
        #request failed, activating panic mode
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinished(String parsingKey) {
        #here i plan to dismiss the notification box, 
        #but this doesn't seem to be the correct approach 
        #as the box is still there
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a proper solution how to dismiss the notification box? A UI response of the onClick event is currently not necessary. Or do I have to send a new Intent from my MessagingService, that kinda overrides the previous notification?

For more clarity this is how I create my notification:

```
Notification notification;

        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), REQUEST_CODE, activityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, PushReceiver.class);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("error_id", remoteMessage.getData().get("id"));
        PendingIntent actionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, REQUEST_CODE, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("notification_title"))
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("notification_text"))
                .setSound(settingsHandlerInstance.getRingtoneUri())
                .setVibrate(settingsHandlerInstance.shouldVibrateOnPush() ? new long[] {0, 500, 200, 500, 0} : new long[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0 })
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Übernehmen", actionIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();
```

Comment: You can call "cancel(int id)" on the NotificationManager object. But, you must keep track of the notification id.

Comment: so to speak, can I pass the notification_id as an intent extra and call cancel() inside the pushReceiver?

Comment: yes, try it and see if it works for you. Make sure you can reach the NotificationManager object from the pushReceiver

Comment: That could be a caveat, the Notification manager is an attribute of my MessagingService. Does it have to be the same object?

Comment: is there any way to pass the NotificationManagerCompat to my BroadcastReceiver by intent?

Comment: One way is to make the NotificationManagerCompat object public static. Or make a class that extends NotificationManagerCompat and implements serializable or parcelable in order to be able to pass an object in a bundle.

Comment: Guess I'll try the second approach then, but thanks for the help already

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191669/discussion-between-procra-and-mena).

Answer (score 0):

Where are you showing the notification details.

```
int notifId = new Random().nextInt();
PendingIntent dismissIntent = NotificationActivity.getDismissIntent(notifId, context);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
        .setContentTitle("Title")
        .setContentText("Content Text")
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        //You use addAction to include the dismiss button. The click action is to remove the notification. You can handle any action here as desired to function with the dismiss button.
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_cancel, "Dismiss", dismissIntent);

NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notifManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
```

Comment: what are you trying to say with this random code snippet?

Comment: Seems possible to me, but I want the notification to be dismissed after an action button is clicked, that does something different. I'll add the code where I create my Notification in a second

Comment: That's what .addAction does. It will dismiss the notification after dismiss is clicked.

Comment: But I want to perform another action by pressing the button, like send a request. And as a callback when the response comes back to dismiss the notification.

Comment: Oh okay. You could share where you create your notification. @TimCastelijns I may not understand what you mean by "random code snippet". You have a better solution that what I've shared which ofcourse works for me?

Comment: the point is that I'm not sure what you shared. You just post code without any explanation about what it does or why it is needed

Comment: I have edited my answer and added a comment. Works better?